# How to reconstruct a quadrilateral ABCD only using compass and straight edge?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-construction, geometric-transformation

Reconstruct a quadrilateral ABCD given length of its sides and the length of the midline between the first and third sides (namely all the segments drawn in the given figure) using compass and straight edge.  The method is parallel translation but i don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: The amount of white space is just ... heinous.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool You could edit/ delete extra white space no.. ?

Comment: @Narasimham This should be the OP's job.  Not mine.

Comment: If we allow all kinds of quadrilaterals (i.e., nonsimple or nonconvex quadrilaterals are allowed), then I think for parameters $a=AB$, $b=BC$, $c=CD$, $d=DA$, and $m=EF$, there are $0$, $1$, or $2$ possible quadrilaterals up to congruence (the reason being that you have to solve two quadratic polynomial equations to get the location of $A$, and then the reflection about $EF$ halves the possible number of quadrilaterals).  I'm not sure how to construct them, though.  Is it even possible to end up with two noncongruence convex quadrilaterals with the same parameters?

Comment: @endgameendgame With a numerical example mentioning below  how I understood it. Say EA=EB=3,DF=FC=5; BC=EF=9.  Then the remaining side AD should lie between two bounds ( that can be found). You cannot specify it arbitrarily..to be 2 or 20 for example. The problem should mention the conditions.In other words if a formula is found and length values plugged in, it  should supply only real and no imaginary solutions for angles contained for the two configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really an interesting problem, which appears to be trivial. However, the only solution I can think of is not that trivial:

[image]

Let $M, N$ be the midpoints of $AC, BD$ respectively. Then $EMFN$ is a parallelogram, with $EM=BC/2, MF= AD/2$. So $EMFN$ is constructable from the given data. Now let $M_1$ be the reflection of $E$ about $M$ and $G$ the common midpoint of $MN$ and $EF$. It is trivial that $M_1$ is contructable, and that $\vec{EM_1} = \vec{BC}$. Thus $EBCM_1$ is a parallelogram and so $CM_1=EB = AB/2$. Therefore, we can construct $C$ (note that there are two possible solution here). Once we have $C$,

- $D$ is the reflection of $C$ about $F$
- $B$ is the reflection of $D$ about $N$
- $A$ is the reflection of $B$ about $E$

And we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Reflect $A,B$ and $E$ across $F$ to $A',B'$ and $E'$. Then $AEA'E'$, $BEB'E'$ and $ABA'B'$ are parallelograms. Also $AEE'B'$ is parallelogram. Let $G$ halves $AB'$, then since $F$ halves $EE'$ we see that $AEFG$ is also parallelogram, so we know the length of $FG$.

Now the construction:

- Draw green triangle $AB'D$ (we know all it sides)
- Draw blue triangle $DGF$ (we know all it sides)
- Draw quadrilateral $ABCD$.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

During the construction:

Either BC is fixed by compass and then AD is automatically determined,

or,

AD is fixed and then BC is automatically determined.

However BC and AD cannot both be fixed together.

No construction is possible.

To visualize consider EBCF as a 4-bar mechanism of given link lengths made in steel with EF as fixed link and BC fixed, link AD would break unless made of thin elastic rubber.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand your argument at all.  Why can't $BC$ and $AD$ both be fixed together?  The visualisation makes no sense.  The question is about geometric construction.  How is your $4$-bar mechanism relevant?

Comment: BTW did you attempt to make a geometric construction?

Comment: That is irrelevant.  Just because I can't doesn't mean that a geometric construction doesn't exist.  Unless there is a solid proof that such a task is impossible, then there is no reason to believe that there is no geometric construction for this problem.  You are the one who answered.  You should be able to clarify.

Comment: As far as I can tell, using an algebraic argument , I know that a geometric construction exists.  I just can't find such a construction yet.

Comment: Please share the algebraic argument !

Comment: BTW did you attempt to make an algebraic argument?

Comment: imho it is unnecessary.

Comment: Good luck with the context !

Comment: @Narasimham I think the issue with your answer is that you did not fix just the length of $AD$, but the positions  of $A$ and $D$ as well. If you keep the length of $AD$ fixed, but move the $A$ point on your circle around $E$, then the length of $BC$ will vary.